# R - how to transform the similarity matrix to distance matrix for performing hierarchical clustering?

Tags: r, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to cluster nodes (C1, C2, C3...) of a graph using hclust and my similarity metric is number of links between nodes.

I have data like

```
c = matrix( c(0,1,3,1,0,5,3,5,0), nrow=3, ncol=3)
```

Basically this is a similarity matrix

```
    C1  C2  C3
C1  0   1   3
C2  1   0   5
C3  3   5   0
```

This is an undirected graph where similarity between C1 and C3 is 3 links. I need to transform this data to a suitable dist.matrix like

```
    C1  C2
C2  1
C3  1/3   1/5
```

format based on my similarity metric (#links between two nodes). How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just want your distances to be `1/c`.

The `print` method for a distance matrix prints it in the format you want.

Which suggests `as.dist(1/c)`.

```
> as.dist(1/c)
          1         2
2 1.0000000          
3 0.3333333 0.2000000
```

Is that what you're after?

If you want the diagonal distances to be zero, then you might replace `1/c` there with (say) `ifelse(c==0,0,1/c)`. It should still print the same.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004890/how-to-transform-the-following-similarity-matrix-to-distance-matrix-for-performi) is more appropriate to what I need.